# How to separate an entry into number and string portion and store separately? c#

Tags: c#

In c# how can I receive an input from a user such as,

```
string user_input1 = "1.5i"; 
string user_input2 = "25.9cd"; 
string user_input3 =  "4a";
```

and store them separately eg.

```
int num1 = 1.5; string str1 = "i";
int num2 = 25.9; string str2 = "cd";
int num3 = 4; string str2 = "a";
```

In other word I want to separate the user input into numeric and text portion so I can perform calculation of the numeric portion of the input.
Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string str1, str2, str3;
    double num1, num2, num3;

    SeperateTextAndNumber("1.5i", out str1, out num1);
    SeperateTextAndNumber("25.9cd", out str2, out num2);
    SeperateTextAndNumber("4a", out str3, out num3);
}

public static void SeperateTextAndNumber(string input, out string text, out double number)
{
    var pattern = input.Contains(".") ? @"(\+|-)?([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+))" : @"\d+";
    var result = Regex.Match(input, pattern).Value;

    number = Convert.ToDouble(result);
    text = input.Replace(result, string.Empty);
}
```

Comment: thanks for speedy reply but can you help me out with what is happening in the procedure. `SeparateTextAndNumber` especially at the line `var pattern = input.Contains(...`

Comment: The first pattern will extract numbers with a decimal point in them and the second one just uses `\d` to match integer numbers. So I'm just checking with the string contains a decimal point to see which pattern to use. Does that make sense? The syntax is just `pattern = if statement ? then : else;`

Comment: The `(\+|-)?([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+))` essentially means + or - sign `(\+|-)?` followed by a number of digits `[0-9]+` followed by a decimal point and then a number of digits `(\.[0-9]+)`. There's plenty of sites that help with regex, i.e, http://regexone.com/

Answer (score 0):

Regex is the way to go, but, for something really simple that satisfies the examples you gave, you could do the following:

```
    string user_input1 = "25.9cd";

    char[] arr = user_input1.ToCharArray();
    string num = "";
    string str = "";

    for(int i=0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        if (char.IsNumber(arr[i]) || arr[i] == '.')
        {
            num += arr[i];
        }
        else {
         str += arr[i];
        }
    }

    //you can cast num to an int, however..
    Console.WriteLine(num); //25.9
    Console.WriteLine(str); //cd
```

Comment: Thanks AaronHammond I understand this example. I am gonna use it but if Regex is the way to go I would love to Understand that syntax too. Hopefully he can shed some light or material that could explain.

Comment: regex is a more powerful but much more complex to understand, depending on how the user is inputting the data you may need to do some more work to this. it only really satisfies the exact examples you gave but it;s a starting point.